# java annotation processing: problems generating a new class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm playing with java annotation processing to learn how to generate java code on compile time. I've created an abstract processor that (using javapoet) creates a new class. However I can't manage to make it work.
I've compressed the example in a single java class.
What I'm doing wrong?

When I compile the project I get:

```
Error:java: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.mateuyabar.AnnotProc not found
```

Here is the java code:

```
package com.mateuyabar;

import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;
import com.squareup.javapoet.JavaFile;
import com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec;
import com.squareup.javapoet.TypeSpec;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class AnnotProc extends AbstractProcessor{
    public @interface MyAnnotation {}

    @MyAnnotation
    public static void dummyForAnnotation(){}

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment env) {
        for(Element el:env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)){
            System.out.println(el.asType());
        }

        MethodSpec sampleMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("sampleMethod").addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC).returns(String.class).addParameter(String.class, "param1")
                .addStatement("return $S+$N", "Welcome, ", "name").build();
        TypeSpec customerService = TypeSpec.classBuilder("MyGeneratedClass").addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC).addMethod(sampleMethod).build();
        JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("com.mateuyabar", customerService).build();
        try {
            javaFile.writeTo(System.out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(MyAnnotation.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new com.mateuyabar.MyGeneratedClass().sampleMethod("a"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What command or tool do you use to compile? It seems that javac does not find your class?

Comment: @JPMoresmau I'm using intellij idea build system.

Comment: It seems your environment is configured to run your processor while compiling it, which of course is not possible. You should probably extract your processor in a separate module, compiled without processors.